# Ftp in python 3.6

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I want to transfer some datas from python to a FTP server which don't require a login... From C++ I can transfer datas without authentification so Ftp server s working well.. I want to do same thing in python...

```
ftp=ftplib.FTP('192.168.1.21')
filename= "test.html"
myfile = open('/Users/Univers/Desktop/test.html', 'rb')
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + filename, myfile)
ftp.quit()
```

Something like that but it returns me:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 530 User cannot log in.
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us packet capture (e.g. using Wireshark) or server-side log of both sessions (C++ and Python).

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('127.0.0.1')     # connect to host, default port
ftp.login()                     # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@ default
ftp.retrlines('LIST')           # list directory contents
ftp.quit()
```

I dont see the ftp.login() in your script.

Comment: >>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('192.168.1.21')
>>> ftp.login()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    ftp.login()
  File "C:\Python\lib\ftplib.py", line 418, in login
    resp = self.sendcmd('PASS ' + passwd)
  File "C:\Python\lib\ftplib.py", line 271, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 530 User cannot log in.

Comment: I don't understand, if i make an ftp server with anonymous login (no user or password in FileZilla) myself and use the script, it works fine. What FTP server are you using?

Comment: iis manager ... I really don't know why i can't connect to the server... Like I said... I tryed same routine on C++ and there was no problem...

Comment: What happens if you use ftp.login("","") or ftp.login(None,None)?

Comment: @MusteDaniel Did you find a solution? I'm just curious. :-)

Comment: No, i Didn't :))